# How to find and count MongoDB Compass by year?

Tags: mongodb

I want to count how many data by createdAt per-year. For example i want to count how many data in 2021 (select with createdAt) and how many data in 2022 in MongoDB Compass.

[image]

I dont know how the query with the $project.

My createdAt data example:  `createdAt 2020-11-04T11:20:08.058+00:00`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$group` and `$sum`:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: {
      $dateToString: {
        "date": "$createdAt",
        "format": "%Y"
      }
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    },
  }
})
```

[Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9dbLxs6uX6O) to playground.

Comment: One question again sir, how to add $match?

Comment: What do you want to `$match`?

Comment: I have found the solution sir, thank you.